# Is there a way to use PyCharm on multiple monitors

Tags: macos, pycharm, multiple-monitors

I'm using PyCharm with multiple monitors on Mac OSX (10.10.5), normally you can drag windows off to a separate monitor. In PyCharm that works, but they (and in particular the Run window) snap back to the main monitor.

I've only seen this on the latest PyCharm 5 CE though its possible older versions also had the problem. I've searched all the settings and searched online, but can't find a setting that makes the window stay where it was placed.

Comment: Did you test my solutions?

Comment: I didn't test your solution @acidjunk because of the downside of mucking up every other application with the menu being on the wrong window, i.e. it might be a solution but introduces other worse problems. 

What I do now, is only use the main window for the search & Run, and drag the source files to other windows, still works fairly poorly though, and is still a weakness in an otherwise good tool.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "mucking up every other application with the menu being on the wrong window", the only downside from running 2 pycharm instances seems to be that drag and drop doesn't always works as expected.

Comment: I quote from your proposed solution "The downside of this solution is that you'll have the OSX dock and main menu only on your main monitor."

Comment: So yes there is a way: just run 2 PyCharm instances?

Answer (score 14):

Right click on the tab and select View Mode as Window.
Then you can move the window to another monitor.

Comment: View mode is only available for tool panels and not for editor tabs:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/viewing-modes.html

Comment: Can I double-upvote this please? :D

Comment: I [tried](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375673/371745)!

Comment: @AndreasBergström Looks like you can now "Move tab to new window"

Comment: What @JamesGeddes said, the default shortcut ist Shift+F4

Answer (score 8):

For Ubuntu and Windows users landing up here:

1. Press Shift + F4 or
2. Right-click and select 'Move Tab to New Window'
3. Drag the newly created window to the next screen

Answer (score 7):

It's crappy behaviour from the best python IDE out there.
There is a OSX solution but i'm not sure if you will like it:

You can enable old style multiple screen support again in OSX by going to System Preferences, Mission Control and uncheck "Displays have separate spaces". Now your floating windows will not snap back and you can even extend your PyCharm main window over the screens.

The downside of this solution is that you'll have the OSX dock and main menu only on your main monitor. I hope Jetbrains will fix this behaviour soon.

Another way to achieve what you want is to open multiple instances of the project. When you try to open the project for the second time you can choose "open project in new window". You can drag the new window to the second screen; it won't snap back to your primary monitor.

Answer (score -4):

The best option is to detach an editor window and drag it to your second monitor.

Comment: Are you suggesting something different from what I described Spencer ? I've tried to clarify a bit, I drag the floating "Run" window over, and it snaps back to the main monitor.